# ansible variable name is itself a variable. How to read? Need syntax

Tags: variables, ansible, runtime-error, undefined, lookup

I have an ansible variable defined in a variable file like below:

```
cat myvarsfile.yml
newpass1: oldpass3
newpass2: oldpass9
newpass3: oldpass5
…
```

In my host playbook I load the variable file like below:

```
   - name: Load password variable file
     include_vars: "{{ playbook_dir }}/myvarsfile.yml"
```

When the user passes a parameter say `newpass2` I should consider it as variable and load its value from the `myvarsfile.yml` file.

```
ansible-playbook -i /var/test.hosts test.yml -e mypass="newpass2"
```

I tried the below code considering `old_pass` is not defined; but it does not work.

```
   - debug:
       msg: "The old value for {{ mypass }} is {{ old_pass | default( vars[mypass] ) }}"
```

Getting the below error:

```
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute u'newpass2'\n\nThe error appears to have been in ….
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `myvarsfile.yml` as in your question, given this playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - include_vars: myvarsfile.yml

    - debug:
        msg: "given mypass={{ mypass }}, old password={{old_pass|default(vars[mypass])}}"
```

Running this command:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e mypass=newpass1
```

Produces:

```
PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [include_vars] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "given mypass=newpass1, old password=oldpass3"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I believe that's the behavior you're looking for.